# Letters appear in double on my svg with custom font on mobile

Tags: html, svg, mobile, fonts

I've some issues with SVG. I'm using a custom font on those (Montserrat) which is a google font. I included font-face in my svgs `<def>`. The `font-type` seems to be applied properly. However, the letters appear in double on special policies on mobile. The fact is that on my desktop everything is ok, even in the console when I check the render for iPhone 6/7//8.

The aspect in console on browser: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/30/4/1564068994-inspectconsolemobile.png

The real aspect on my iPhone 6: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/30/4/1564069030-bugonmobile.jpg

If someone can explain to me where is the problem it would be very appreciated!

Thank you all

Inside the def tag of my svg :

```
<style type="text/css">
       <![CDATA[
        @font-face {
            font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
            src: url('../polices/Montserrat-Bold.eot') format('eot'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
            src: url('../polices/Montserrat-Regular.eot') format('eot'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: Montserrat-SemiBold;
            src: url('../polices/Montserrat-SemiBold.eot') format('eot'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
              url('../polices/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
       ]]>
     </style>
```

Inside my html :

```
<object data='./assets/images/landingDesign_tel.svg'></object>
```

EDIT :
Here is the solution to the issue i just found :
Add this to your style tag in the svg :

```
text, tspan {
        font-weight: normal;
      }
```

Full explanation can be found here : https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left/

Comment: Both images are same

Comment: Thank you ! I just edit my post with good links